# Does Suggestions sorting method work in user profile?

Tags: support

I made some edit suggestions to others' questions earlier, but nothing shows up under *Activity - All Actions - Suggestions* in my User Profile. So I can't check whether they were accepted or rejected, by whom, and for what reason.

I wonder if its the site bug, or suggestions on Meta are reflected somewhat different compare to the main site? Also, can a user repeat again similar edit suggestion if it was already rejected, and to what degree its expected to vary?